# Decorations on circuitikz elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz, decorations

I was trying to create a schematic with TikZ that looks like hand drawn. Unfortunately circuitikz seems not to work nicely with the decorations library. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=0.2pt},
    every path/.append style=decorate,
    %every node/.append style=decorate % <- error
    ]

    \path (0,0) node[op amp] (oa) {{\small $OA_1$}};    

    \draw (oa.-) -- ++($(oa.-)-(oa.+)$) coordinate(tmp) to[R,l=$R$] (tmp -| oa.out) -- (oa.out);
    \draw (oa.-) to[short,*-,i_<=$I_\text{in}$] ++($(oa.center)-(oa.bout)$);
    \draw (oa.+) to[short,-o] ++ ($(oa.in up)-(oa.bin up)$) node[left]{$V_\text{ref}$};
    \draw (oa.out) to[short,*-o] ++ ($(oa.out)-(oa.bout)$) node[right]{$V_\text{out}$};

    \path (oa.+ -| oa.out) node [rectangle, draw, decorate] {test};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The style does not apply to all circuit elements. If I use `every node/.append style=decorate` I get the error:

> Package pgf Error: I cannot decorate an empty path.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I do not think it's easily done. All shape's paths are drawn in the background, in independent paths. I am studying a (possible) hook system to allow this kind of thing, but it's still in its infancy. But I will look at it, but many shapes have subpaths and that makes adding a generic hook to everywhere is quite difficult. Thinking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I suspect that this is almost impossible.

`circuitikz` components are (basically) written as `\behindbackground` elements of the shape. That means that they are drawn with an independent path, stroked independently. That is needed for most (or, at least, a lot of) components because we need to have subpaths with different thicknesses, dashing, arrows, and sometimes colors; and those properties can't be mixed in a single path in Ti*k*Z.

So there are normally different paths in the component drawing commands,  and decorations have to be applied (if I got that correctly) path by path.

I am adding a [kind-of hook system](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/610) to `circuitikz` (hooks are fashionable in LaTeX recently!) but those are just at the start and end of the shape drawing because each shape has a different drawing pattern. I tried to use them to force decoration, to no avail.

I will continue thinking about it, but for now the answer is that no, it's not possible.